# Multiplying Strings

Tags: java, string, for-loop

Say I want to make some "towers" that look something like this:

```
*********
*********
********* *******
********* *******
********* ******* ***************
********* ******* ***************
********* ******* ***************
********* ******* ***************
********* ******* ***************
********* ******* ***************
********* ******* ***************
```

If I ask the user to input three different numbers for the widths of the towers and a random integers will make up the length, how can I make a for loop that will multiply "*" times the number the user entered for width? This is what I have so far:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < randInt1; i++){

            // I would like to do something like 
            // System.out.print("*") * width1
            // and do this for all three towers so that they 
            // print next to each other separated by a space
        }
```

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, or others with similar problems, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: What do you mean by "length"? Is it the "height" of each column?

Comment: @BingLu Yes It's meant to be the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing your for loop with below code block should work.

```
int highest = Math.max(randInt1, Math.max(randInt2, randInt3));
for(int i = highest; i > 0; i--){
    printColumn(width1, randInt1, i);
    System.out.print(" ");

    printColumn(width2, randInt2, i);
    System.out.print(" ");

    printColumn(width3, randInt3, i);
    System.out.println();
}
```

And adding a helper method

```
private static void printColumn(int columnWidth, int columnHeight, int currentHeight) {
    for(int j = columnWidth;j > 0;j--) {
        if(columnHeight - currentHeight >= 0) {
            System.out.print("*");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

You're not able to "Multiply" "*"s. You may want to print your tower line by line and use space to align each column.

Comment: If you'll refactor out the inner for-loop to avoid code duplication - you'll get my vote ;)

Comment: Much better - that's the way to go! :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution will be joining either stars or white-spaces for each tower per line. Pay attention to `generateString()` which returns a string at the width of the related tower!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // hardcoded settings (example) 
    // in your case you'll read it from the user
    Integer[] widths = {5, 4, 6};
    Integer[] heights = {5, 4, 6};

    // subtract max-1 from the heights
    int max = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(heights)) - 1;
    for (int i=0; i<heights.length; i++)
        heights[i] -= max;


    // print the towers
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++){
        String line = "";
        for (int j=0; j<widths.length; j++) {
            if (heights[j] > 0)
                line += generateString("*", widths[j]) + " ";
            else
                line += generateString(" ", widths[j]) + " ";
            heights[j] += 1;
        }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}

private static String generateString(String str, int times) {
    return String.format("%1$" + times + "s", str).replace(" ", str);
}
```